# peer didn't accept DH group MODP_2048, it requested MODP_1024

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, syslog, site-to-site-vpn

hope somebody can help me, I am trying to set up a VPN between Google CLoud VPN and Palo Alto. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my log:

```
D  remote host is behind NAT 
D  authentication of '35.xxx.xxx.xxx' (myself) with pre-shared key 
I  establishing CHILD_SA vpn_103.xxx.xxx.xxx 
D  generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(EAP_ONLY) ] 
D  sending packet: from 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] (416 bytes) 
D  received packet: from 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] to 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] (80 bytes) 
D  parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(NO_PROP) ] 
D  IDr payload missing 
D  generating INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ] 
D  sending packet: from 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] (80 bytes) 
D  creating acquire job for policy with reqid {1} 
I  initiating IKE_SA vpn_103.xxx.xxx.xxx[159] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx 
D  generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ] 
D  sending packet: from 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (892 bytes) 
D  received packet: from 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (38 bytes) 
D  parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ] 
D  peer didn't accept DH group MODP_2048, it requested MODP_1024 
I  initiating IKE_SA vpn_103.xxx.xxx.xxx[159] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx 
D  generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) ] 
D  sending packet: from 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (764 bytes) 
D  received packet: from 103.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 35.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (304 bytes) 
D  parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) ] 
D  remote host is behind NAT
```

I noticed error: "peer didn't accept DH group MODP_2048, it requested MODP_1024"

My peer device (Palo Alto) has Group 2 (MODP_1024). My question is, How to set DH Group in GCP to Group 2 (MODP_1024)?

Comment: Unless the (weak) modp1024 DH group is disabled somehow (which should result in a different error message), that's not really an error, it just means there will be a retry with that group. The peers should still be able to establish the SA, so check what happens after these log messages.

Comment: So, what should I do now? just wait?
Now my VPN tunnel status is "First handshake". Does it really needs this long to establish a VPN connection?

Comment: As I said, read the log. I doubt what you posted is complete, there must be more messages following.

Comment: Finally I established the connection. Thank @ecdsa